# Can someone explain this line from the Judy data structure documentation?

Tags: data-structures, judy-array

http://judy.sourceforge.net/downloads/10minutes.htm

Question -- Why would only 4 cache-line fills be required? Isn't the cache line 64-bytes these days?

> With an expanse of 2^32 (or 256^4), a maximum of 4 cache-line fills
> would be required for a worst-case highly populated 256-ary digital
> tree access. In an expanse of 2^64 (or 256^8), 8 cache-line fills
> would be the worst case. In practice, Judy does much better than this.
> The reason is (in part) due to the fact "density" of the keys is
> seldom the lowest possible number in a "majority" of the sub-expanses.
> It takes high density combined with high population to increase the
> depth of a Judy tree. It would take a long time to explain why. The
> short version is an analogy with sand. It takes a lot of sand to build
> a tall sand pile, especially if it takes 256 grains to support 1 grain
> above it. In a 64-bit Judy, it would probably require more RAM than
> exists on this planet to get it to have 8 levels. A binary tree
> reaches 8 levels with a population of 256. It is truly remarkable to
> me how much research has been done on binary trees and still being
> taught.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 256-ary tree, so to traverse down to a single item in a densely populated tree with 32-bit keys, you need to descend log<sub>256</sub>(2<sup>32</sup>) = 4 levels.

To do that in 4 cache line fills, you need each 256-ary internal node, including encoded pointers to its 256 children, to fit into a single cache line.  A cache line is only 512 bits, so that's pretty impressive.